# JavaScript/jQuery step-by-step registration form

Tags: javascript

Is there any JavaScript/jQuery library for creating step-by-step forms? It's better if it has some animations in steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://thecodemine.org/
By step by step do you mean this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should be looking for a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) plugin rather than framework for it. Here's a nice animated form registration demo: http://demos.9lessons.info/slidereg/demo.html

Tutorial: *[Gravity Registration Form with jQuery](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/gravity-registration-form-with-jquery.html)*

And there's a nice jQuery plugin that might be helpful, *[jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)*.